# How to correctly declare/assign Kotlin generic interface and data class

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am investigating Kotlin Generics using Interfaces, Inner Interfaces and data classes.

I have declared the following:

```
interface MyInterface<X, Y> {

    interface MyInnerInterface<Y> : MyInterface<Nothing, Y> {
        val myY: Y
    }

    interface MySecondInnerInterface<X, Y> : MyInterface<X, Y> {
        val myX: X
        fun something(myY: Y): MyDataClass<Class<MySecondInnerInterface<X, Y>>, MyInnerInterface<Y>>
    }
}

data class MyDataClass<A, B>(
    val klass: Class<MyInterface.MySecondInnerInterface<A, B>>,
    val myInnerInterface: MyInterface.MyInnerInterface<B>
)
```

I employ the above within a sealed class:-

```
sealed class Investigation<L, M> : MyInterface<L, M> {

    data class MySecondInnerOne(override val myX: String) : MyInterface.MySecondInnerInterface<String, Long> {
        private data class MyInnerOne(override val myY: Long) : MyInterface.MyInnerInterface<Long>

        override fun something(myY: Long): MyDataClass<Class<MyInterface.MySecondInnerInterface<String, Long>>, MyInterface.MyInnerInterface<Long>>
        = MyDataClass(this@MySecondInnerOne::class.java, MyInnerOne(myY)) // COMPILE ERROR!!!!!
    }
```

The above generates a compile time error, most of which I do not understand as follows:-

[image]

I cannot see how to resolve all these errors.

What refactors are necessary to enable me to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I think it is caused by generic types since you cannot get their type. For example if you try List<String>::class.java you would get an error. It could be solved by using inline function with reified keyword however reified cannot be applied to interfaces of abstract definitions.